# Determining the closed form of a particular inhomogeneous recursive relation

Tags: closed-form, recursion

In my research I have come to the point where I would like to know the expression for $a_n$ which satisfies
\begin{equation}
a_n=2a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}+4, \hspace{4mm}a_1=3, \hspace{2mm}a_2=9
\end{equation}

Let me tell you where this come from. I have this sequence of numbers:
\begin{equation}
3,9,19,33,51,...
\end{equation}
You can see that the difference between two numbers is equal to the difference between the previous two numbers, increased by 4, e.g., $9-3=6$, $19-9=10=6+4$, ...
Hence I can write
\begin{equation}
a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=a_{n+1}-a_{n}+4
\end{equation}
from which the above equation follows.

I am aware of the general procedure for solving these recursive equations. I started to look for a solution of the homogeneous equation, by setting $a_n=Ac^n$. This gives the equation $c^2-2c+1=0$, solved by $c=1$.
Then I looked for a particular solution, say $a_n=b$. However, this gives $b=2b-b+4$, from which $4=0$. Clearly this method does not work here.

Do you have an idea on how to find $a_n$? Does this equation even have a closed solution?

Comment: Are you sure you want to define $a_n$ in terms of higher elements, e.g., $a_{n+1}$ and $a_{n+2}$?

Comment: I updated my answer and explain where the equation comes from. But does it make a huge difference to define it in terms of higher elements rather than lower elements?

Comment: Yes it does.  Suppose you wanted just the value of $a_9$.  You go to your formula and see you need $a_{11}$. How would you find *that*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$c=1$ is a double root of your characteristic equation $c^2-2c+1=0$, so that gives not just one but two linearly independent solutions of the homogeneous equation: $a_n = 1$ and $a_n = n$.  Since polynomials of degree $0$ and $1$ are solution of the homogeneous equation, your particular solution should be of the form $a_n = b n^2$.

You should end up with $a_n = 2 n^2 + 1$.

BTW, you could also try looking up your sequence in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/search?q=3%2C9%2C19%2C33%2C51&sort=&language=&go=Search).

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$
\eqalign{
  & a_{\,n + 2}  - 2a_{\,n + 1}  + a_{\,n}  = \Delta ^{\,2} a_{\,n}  = 4\quad  \Rightarrow   \cr 
  &  \Rightarrow \quad a_{\,n}  = {4 \over {2!}}n^{\,\underline {\,2\,} }
  + c_{\,1} n^{\,\underline {\,1\,} }  + c_{\,0} n^{\,\underline {\,0\,} }  =   \cr 
  &  = 2n\left( {n - 1} \right) + c_{\,1} n + c_{\,0}  \cr} 
$$
where $n^{\,\underline {\,m\,} }$ indicates the Falling Factorial.